# Capture files send over bluetooth in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet, obex

I'm creating a WPF application for sending and receiving files over bluetooth. I'm using 32feet library for the same. I can send files using ObexObjectPush bluetooth service.

But when files are received using the technique, specified [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3789b7/how-to-send-data-through-bluetooth-in-a-wpf-application-usin/), are not captured by my application, instead my computer captures it.

Here is my code:

```
  private void Listener(CancellationTokenSource token)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                using (var client = _listener.AcceptBluetoothClient())
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()))
                    {
                        try
                        {  
                           // ...  Custom operation
                          //....
                        }
                        catch (IOException ex)
                        {                               
                            client.Close();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // todo handle the exception
        }
    }
```

All I want to do is to capture all file received using bluetooth. Presently my system shows a popup for receiving file. I want to override this behaviour and want my application to receive it.

Any help in this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what streamReader doing here?I mean is'nt it receiving file?

Comment: It doesn't get trigger, instead a windows popup comes up that shows it is receiving a file.

Comment: did you create SenderBluetoothService?

Comment: I am sending data from android device not from WPF application. Although, the SenderBluetoothService I have created for WPF sends data to android device successfully.

Comment: Which Bluetooth drivers do you use? If it is BlueSoleil or Toshiba then they have build-in OPP server and receives the file. You have to disable biild-in services first.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko how do I have to disable the built-in services ?

Comment: It depends on Bluetooth drivers you use. Of course that is if you are taling about Accept File dialog. If you are talning about System pairing dialog this is the other question. But that dialog can also be disabled.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I use intel PROSET/Wireless software for BT driver. Please guide me how do I disable its in-built services.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I do not know how PROSET (because it is something not popular) wotjs but I am sure that it has some settings dialog where you can enable and disable some settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer is capturing the received files because it has its own Bluetooth handler up and running and listening for requests.

You need to stop the "**Bluetooth OBEX Service**" Windows service on your computer, in order to prevent it from handling the received files instead of your WPF application.

NOTE: I prefer to disable the "**Bluetooth OBEX Service**" Windows service instead of stopping it, because it seems -at some circumstances- there are some other services cause this service to be started automatically again. By disabling it, you will avoid any future confusion.